# Complex roots for a polynome

Tags: polynomials

I have to find roots for the following polynome :

$\large P(X)=X^6 -X^3 +1-i$

I already found complex roots for the polynome  $X^2 -X +1-i$

$\large -i ,  1+i$

but I was confused about conjugates . for  $\large z^3= -i$. We have 3 roots 
$\large e^{-\pi/6}, e^{\pi/2} , e^{7\pi/6} $

> If I take only those roots and their conjugates I will have 6 roots for the the polynome above. what's about the second root (1+i $)?

Comment: as you found out by solving quadratic equation, the roots do not have to be conjugates when we have complex coefficients

Answer (score 3):

The roots of a polynomial are couple of conjugate numbers only if the coefficients are real numbers. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem).

Comment: Then my solution is valid, and all I have to do Is to look for roots   $z^3=1+I$ and this way I will have six roots in all.  Thanks

Comment: Yes. You are right. From $x^3=1+i$ you have the other 3 roots.